# Getting duplicates elements in an sqlserver table

Tags: t-sql

I want to get all duplicates elements in a table using transact-sql.

I know how to get distinct elements but need to get all the duplicates.
I'm using sql server 2017 express edition in ubuntu 18.04

```
SELECT DISTINCT myField FROM myDb.dbo.myTable
```

This get me the distincts elements, but not the duplicates.
For example i have this data:
[image]

And i want to get something like this:

[image]

Please any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you all of the columns of the rows where a value in myField occurs more than once.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#myTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #myTable;

CREATE TABLE #myTable
(
    Id INT
  , myField INT
  , Date DATE
);

INSERT INTO #myTable (Id, myField, Date) VALUES (1, 1, '2019-05-10');
INSERT INTO #myTable (Id, myField, Date) VALUES (2, 2, '2019-05-10');
INSERT INTO #myTable (Id, myField, Date) VALUES (3, 1, '2019-05-10');
INSERT INTO #myTable (Id, myField, Date) VALUES (4, 3, '2019-05-10');
INSERT INTO #myTable (Id, myField, Date) VALUES (5, 2, '2019-05-10');
INSERT INTO #myTable (Id, myField, Date) VALUES (6, 4, '2019-05-10');

SELECT * FROM #myTable ORDER BY Id;

SELECT     a.*
FROM       #myTable AS a
INNER JOIN (
               SELECT   myField
                      , COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
               FROM     #myTable
               GROUP BY myField
               HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
           )        AS b ON a.myField = b.myField
ORDER BY   a.myField;
```

If that is not what you are looking for, please provide some sample data and what you are expecting the output to be.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the creation of a temp table, populating it with the test data you provided, querying the entire table, and finally querying what you want to get.